# Mybatis can set value with reflection?

Tags: mybatis

Mybatis can set value with reflection?
I have a class , and it has a property , it's setter is protected . So I have to use reflection to set this value ? Mybatis can work ?

Answer (score 5):

yes, mybatis use reflect to set value.
in Reflator.java(mybatis 3.3.0), mybatis will config set method.

```
private void addSetMethods(Class<?> cls) {
    Map<String, List<Method>> conflictingSetters = new HashMap<String, List<Method>>();
    Method[] methods = getClassMethods(cls);
    for (Method method : methods) {
      String name = method.getName();
      if (name.startsWith("set") && name.length() > 3) {
        if (method.getParameterTypes().length == 1) {
          name = PropertyNamer.methodToProperty(name);
          addMethodConflict(conflictingSetters, name, method);
        }
      }
    }
    resolveSetterConflicts(conflictingSetters);
  }
```

if your class do not have set method, when addSetFields it will add new SetInvoker for the field:

```
private void addSetField(Field field) {
    if (isValidPropertyName(field.getName())) {
      setMethods.put(field.getName(), new SetFieldInvoker(field));
      setTypes.put(field.getName(), field.getType());
    }
  }
```

and the SetFieldInvoker is like this:

```
/**
 * @author Clinton Begin
 */
public class SetFieldInvoker implements Invoker {
  private Field field;

  public SetFieldInvoker(Field field) {
    this.field = field;
  }

  @Override
  public Object invoke(Object target, Object[] args) throws IllegalAccessException, InvocationTargetException {
    field.set(target, args[0]);
    return null;
  }

  @Override
  public Class<?> getType() {
    return field.getType();
  }
}
```

the DefaultResultSetHandler calls BeanWrapper's setBeanProperty method will call getSetInvoker

```
private void setBeanProperty(PropertyTokenizer prop, Object object, Object value) {
    try {
      Invoker method = metaClass.getSetInvoker(prop.getName());
      Object[] params = {value};
      try {
        method.invoke(object, params);
      } catch (Throwable t) {
        throw ExceptionUtil.unwrapThrowable(t);
      }
    } catch (Throwable t) {
      throw new ReflectionException("Could not set property '" + prop.getName() + "' of '" + object.getClass() + "' with value '" + value + "' Cause: " + t.toString(), t);
    }
  }
```

the whole call chain maybe like this:
DefaultSqlSession##selectList -->SimpleExecutor##doQuery --> SimpleStatementHandler##query --> DefaultResultSetHandler##handleResultSets

Comment: Thank you, got it!